# WiFi not working after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel

I have a notebook Kanji Tamura Duo, on which I had Windows10 an everything worked just fine. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and the WiFi does not work. It lets me turn it on and then when I go to "Select Network" gets stuck on "no networks" (I know that there are networks available). I been looking on the internet but i couldn't find a fix. I'll include some of the outputs that I've tried in case they are useful.
I've already rolled back to Win10, I'm leaving the tread open since there are others with the same problem.

```
edelmiro@Distrito8:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for edelmiro: 
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s21f0u2
       serial: ea:a7:73:e1:fb:65
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.43 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlx54c9dfb805ef
       serial: 54:c9:df:b8:05:ef
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

edelmiro@Distrito8:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a8c (rev 0b)
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
Memory at 91110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2212
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Device 1c6c:122a
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
Memory at 91118000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
Memory at 91145000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me

00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
Memory at 9111c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Memory at 91142000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
Memory at 91141000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI (rev 0b) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 120
Memory at 91100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
Memory at 91140000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9113f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
Memory at 9113e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9113d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
Memory at 9113c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9113b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
Memory at 9113a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91139000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
Memory at 91138000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91137000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
Memory at 91136000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91135000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
Memory at 91134000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91133000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
Memory at 91132000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91131000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 4
Memory at 91130000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9112f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
Memory at 9112e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9112d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 6
Memory at 91143000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91144000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
Memory at 9112c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9112b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
Memory at 9112a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91129000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
Memory at 91128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91127000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
Memory at 91126000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91125000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:1b.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
Memory at 91124000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91123000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
Memory at 91122000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 91121000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:1e.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 01)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
Memory at 91120000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at 9111f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at 9111e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `rfkill list all`? When I upgraded, my wireless was "hard blocked" until I disabled and re-enabled the WLAN in BIOS and allowed simultaneous LAN/WLAN connection (in BIOS). The new drivers seem to look more closely at BIOS settings.

Comment: None was hard blocked on the output of rfkill, anyways it magically fixed it self short after I post this... I didn't do anything and sudenlly it was working. Should I delete the post or marked as solved?

Comment: After a reboot it does not work again...

Comment: im very disappointed when trying the LTS 18.04 version of ubuntu. Im also getting the same issue. Other suggest to disable secure boot, but didnt work in me. Might work in your case.

Comment: Have you tried simply installing the proper WiFi drivers as shown here? http://sourcedigit.com/21104-how-to-enable-wifi-in-ubuntu-linux/ Usually it is required after every system update.

Comment: yes I tried, no additional drivers were available on that tab.