# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Unmanaged Wifi

Tags: networking, server, wireless, network-manager, internet

I'm working on Ubuntu Server 18.04 and I'm trying to setup the Wifi.

I've tried many ways to setup the wifi but I didn't found any working solution. I'm now trying `nmcli` tool.

When I do `nmcli d` to have the list of available network interfaces, I have the following output:

```
DEVICE    TYPE    STATE        CONNECTION
wlan0     wifi    unmanaged    --
```

On the other hand, the command `nmcli general` shows me:

```
STATE        CONNECTIVITY    WIFI-HW    WIFI
connected    full            enabled    enable
```

What does it mean and how to solve it ?

I tried to set `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Also, when I check if my hardware is working, I have no result:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wlan
$
```

And if I do `sudo lshw -class network` :

```
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    physical id:1
    logical name: wlan0
    serial: 00:23:a7:fe:e4:dc
    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RSI-SDIO WLAN driverversion=4.15.0-1038-oem firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I also tried to edit wpa_supplicant.conf and also tried to use netplan, without success.

I don't have any other wired connection so the wifi it's my only solution to have internet on my device. Thus, I cannot install any new package to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: can you add the exact model of your card and laptop to your post please?

Comment: my "laptop" is the [Dell Edge Gateway 3003](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/cty/pdp/spd/dell-edge-gateway-3003) with these [specification](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/dell-edge-gateway-3000-series/dell-edge_gateway-3003-specs/wireless-lan?guid=guid-83c023ab-0a1c-45f3-a1f6-30b4e4c6667e&lang=en-us)

Comment: apparently you can get temporary internet via usb tethering with a 3G/4/G capable phone. once you've done that you can install packages to try and solve the problem. Does this answer help ? https://askubuntu.com/a/1048786/307184 if not read through this : https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/307184 and the answers below it

Comment: Yes I can use usb tethering to have internet access. But it doesn't solve my problem. I still cannot connect to wifi

Comment: Solved. My access point was 5Ghz whereas my device only supports 2.4Ghz

Comment: oh ok. this wasn't a ubuntu or a driver issue, phew!